# Permission denied running sha256sum. How do I check the iso files?

Tags: 18.04, permissions, checksums, sha256

When I run:

```
sha256sum -c SHA256SUMS | grep OK
```

Output:

```
sha256sum: ubuntu-18.04.2-desktop-amd64.iso: permission denied
sha256sum: ubuntu-18.04.2-live-server-amd64.iso: no such file or directory
sha256sum: 2 listed files could not be read
```

When I run:

```
sha256sum -c SHA256SUMS 2>&1 | grep OK
```

there is no output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both ISO files should be present in the same folder as where the `sha256sum` command is executed, and should be readable by you. Thus, check whether the files are present in the current directory, and check their permissions. The command `ls -l | grep .iso` will list all `.iso` files present in the current directory, along with their permissions.

The output you get suggests

1. `ubuntu-18.04.2-desktop-amd64.iso` is present, but you do not have the permissions to read the contents of the file. You can enable the read permission, but you probably will need to do so as root: `sudo chmod ugo+r ubuntu-18.04.2-desktop-amd64.iso`. This sets the "read" permission for the owner of the file, the group that owns the file and others.
2. `ubuntu-18.04.2-live-server-amd64.iso` is not present. If you did download it, you will probably find it in a different folder than that where you run the command. Move it to the same folder as where you run the command.

Answer (score 1):

- permission denied means you do not own the file.
- 2 methods of getting rid of that notification:

  - change the owner with `sudo chown $USER:$USER ubuntu-18.04.2-desktop-amd64.iso ubuntu-18.04.2-live-server-amd64.iso
  - use `sudo sha256sum -c SHA256SUMS | grep OK`

  In both cases you need to provide the admin password. If you account is not an admin you will need to ask that user.

> When I run:
>
> ```
> sha256sum -c SHA256SUMS 2>&1 | grep OK
> ```
>
> there is no output.

What did you expect? you tell it to discard error messages so you do not get any.